# How do I make my images show 3x3, why do the last 2 go to the next row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, rows

Why don't my last 2 images in my 3x3 grid of images go to the next row below and my images aren't showing, how do I fix this?

http://dev.picstrap.com/

I'm still really new at this kind of stuff, sorry if this is a beginner question, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a defined

```
#gallery li:nth-child(4n) {
    clear: left;
}
```

in the responsive.css (might be an external lib you are using).

That's why your 8th li (4*2) gets that behaviour. You can overwrite it with something like:

```
#gallery li:nth-child(4n) {
    clear: none;
}
```

Just make sure your selector weights more than the default.

Answer (score 0):

you can split array using array_chunk($array,3);

```
<?php @foreach (array_chunk($array,3) as $rows){ ?>
     <div class="row">
          <?php @foreach ($rows as $row){ ?>
              <div class='col-lg-4'> <!--split 12 column into 4x3-->
                 images+ description
              </div>
          <?php } ?>
      </div>
<?php } ?>
```